# Converter números escritos com separador de milhar para valor numérico no R

Tags: r

Tenho o seguinte número que estou importando de um site, coloquei da maneira a seguir para não precisar colocar todo o código de importação dos dados

```
a <- as.character("353.636.000.000")
```

Gostaria de transformar isso em um número, porém não estou conseguindo

Tentei fazer da seguinte maneira, separar os termos pelo `.` e depois unir novamente e transformar em número, porém, não deu certo

```
temp2 <- strsplit(temp2, ".")
```

Preciso que resulte em um objeto `a` com valor de `353636000000`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Também é possível resolver o problema com `R` base:

```
a <- as.character("353.636.000.000")
as.numeric(gsub("\\.", "", a))
## [1] 3.53636e+11
```

A função `gsub` é equivalente a um comando do tipo *Localizar e substituir*. Sua sintaxe permite que

1. procuremos uma string (no caso, `.`, mas temos que colocar os caracteres `\\` para evitar que o `R` entenda isso como uma expressão regular)
2. substituamos a string procurada por nada (neste exemplo, `""` é o indicativo disso)
3. em um determinado objeto, que no exemplo é o caracter `a`

Comment: muito bom, obrigado

Answer (score 6):

Com `stringr` você pode fazer isso:

```
library(tidyverse)

b <- a %>% 
  str_replace_all(pattern = '[.]', '') %>% 
  as.numeric()

class(b)
[1] "numeric"
```

Comment: excelente, muito obrigado